# what can watir's new "alert API" actually do?

Tags: watir

I just read that new Watir version (3.1.0) has "support for Alert API". What can I actually do with this API?

Is it meant for dealing with javascript popup windows? If so, what command can I use to click "OK" in popup window? Or how can I read title & text of popup window?

I tried "`browser.alert.ok`" after updating Watir to 3.1.0 but just got some error message...

(There is not yet any clear documentation about this, and trying to interpret the source code is not my strongest side...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert API is for dealing with JavaScript popups.

`browser.alert.ok` should work. Could you provide the error message?

I am not sure about getting popup title, but you can get it's text with `browser.alert.text`

More information: http://watir.github.io/docs/javascript-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

> browser.alert.ok should work. Could you provide the error message?

Sure. First, here is Watir code that I used:

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.start "www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert"
b.maximize
b.frame(:name, "view").button(:text, "Show alert box").click_no_wait
sleep 2
b.alert.ok
```

And here is the error message:

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/functions.rb:319: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0012 p:---- s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 CFUNC  :enum_child_windows
c:0011 p:0065 s:0046 b:0046 l:002478 d:002478 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:319
c:0010 p:0015 s:0038 b:0038 l:0018e4 d:0018e4 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:200
c:0009 p:0025 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/functions.rb:147
c:0008 p:0035 s:0025 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/win_32/window.rb:247
c:0007 p:0017 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/window.rb:220
c:0006 p:---- s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 FINISH
c:0005 p:0079 s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/alert.rb:38
c:0004 p:0011 s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 METHOD C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.
9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/alert.rb:27
c:0003 p:0107 s:0007 b:0007 l:00043c d:0018c0 EVAL   C:/watir_testit/pop.rb:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH

### c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:00043c d:00043c TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
C:/watir_testit/pop.rb:6:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-classic/dialog
s/alert.rb:27:in`ok'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-classic/dialog
s/alert.rb:38:in `dialog'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/window.rb:
220:in`method_missing'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/window.rb:247:in `child'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/functions.rb:147:in`child_window_locators'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/functions.rb:200:in `control_hwnd'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/functions.rb:319:in`find_hwnd'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rautomation-0.7.2/lib/rautomation/adapter/wi
n_32/functions.rb:319:in `enum_child_windows'

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: There exists a segmentation fault bug in some versions of ffi gem. Please update your ffi gem and you should not get that problem anymore. You can update it with gem install ffi or if using bundler, then bundle update ffi.

Comment: Please update the original question, do not put the update in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately updating ffi gem did not help. "browser.alert.ok" still crashes ruby. Tested on two different computers, both running Windows XP and IE8.